# How to set up a correct size of buffer of the structure?

Tags: java, jna

I have a documentation for DLL which I have to use where is defined a structure which is an argument to one of the native mathod.

It looks like here:

```
typedef struct
{
UNUM32 uiModuleState;
UNUM32 uiSerialNumber;
UNUM32 uiVCIIf;
UNUM32 uiModuleType;
CHAR8 szModuleName[256];
}
VTX_RT_VCI_ITEM;
typedef struct
{
UNUM32 uiNumVCIItems;
VTX_RT_VCI_ITEM * pVCIItems;
}
VTX_RT_VCI_ITEM_LIST;
Calling Convention:
SNUM32 VtxRtGetModuleIds( IO UNUM32* puiBufferLen,
IO VTX_RT_VCI_ITEM_LIST* pVCIItemList);
```

I have modeled that structure in the JNA like here

VTX_RT_VCI_ITEM

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "uiModuleState",
                        "uiSerialNumber",
                        "uiVCIIf",
                        "uiModuleType",
                        "szModuleName" })
public class VtxRtVciItem extends Structure
{
    public int uiModuleState;

    public int uiSerialNumber;

    public int uiVCIIf;

    public int uiModuleType;

    public char[] szModuleName = new char[VciRuntimeAPI.VTX_RT_SMALL_BUF_SIZE];

    public static class ByReference extends VtxRtVciItem implements Structure.ByReference {}

    public static class ByValue extends VtxRtVciItem implements Structure.ByValue {}

    public VtxRtVciItem()
    {
        super();
        read();
    }
}
```

VTX_RT_VCI_ITEM_LIST

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "uiNumVCIItems",
                        "pVCIItems" })
public class VtxRtVciItemList extends Structure
{
    public int uiNumVCIItems;

    public VtxRtVciItem.ByReference pVCIItems;

    public VtxRtVciItemList()
    {
        super();

    }
}
```

A first argument is described as follow 
puiBufferLen
Size of the buffer pointed to by pVCIItemList.

How to set up a correct buffer size of that structure?

I was trying to do something like here but the size of that structure is 8 which means that VtxRtVciItem is not callculated.

```
VtxRtVciItemList vtxRtVciItemList = new VtxRtVciItemList();
IntByReference puiBufferLen = new IntByReference();
puiBufferLen.setValue(vtxRtVciItemList.size());
```

Comment: You need to use the Structure's `.size()` method and multiply by the number of elements.   The size should evaluate to 260 bytes (as a sanity check).  You don't need to allocate the memory yourself, though, just create a new instance of the structure and use `toArray(numItems)` on that instance to allocate the memory and create an array, then pass the first element of that array to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `vtxRtVciItemList` is just a structure with the number of list elements and a pointer to the actual list.   The list buffer itself will be the size of each structure in the list (`new VtxRtVciItem().size()`) multiplied by the number of those elements (`uiNumVCIItems`).

You don't show where you actually allocate that buffer, which you'll need to use the `Structure.toArray()` method to do.

I think this is what you want to do, let me know if I've misinterpreted your request.

```
int numItems = 42; // whatever your number of list items is
VtxRtVciItem.ByReference[] vtxRtVciItemPointerArray = 
    (VtxRtVciItem.ByReference[]) new VtxRtVciItem.ByReference().toArray(numItems);
VtxRtVciItemList vtxRtVciItemList = new VtxRtVciItemList();
vtxRtVciItemList.uiNumVCIItems = numItems;
vtxRtVciItemList.pVCIItems = vtxRtVciItemPointerArray[0];
```

And then pass to your function:

```
IntByReference puiBufferLen = 
    new IntByReference(vtxRtVciItemList.uiNumVCIItems * vtxRtVciItemPointerArray[0].size());
VtxRtGetModuleIds(puiBufferLen, pVCIItemList);
```